# how to get control back from axtivex component to windown form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, activex

I am writing a code in vb.net to create a client control front end for a controller card software.
what i have done is created a activeX component on this controller software on my windows form so that i can access its dll.
my problem is when i call a certain method of this software it shifts control to that software since it is waiting for input on that software and my windows form becomes inactive. i cannot do anything on my windows form. 
i want my windows from to be active in all cases.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this - it should fire whenever the form loses focus.

```
Private Sub Form1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave
    Me.Focus()
End Sub
```